# Remove sockjs-node from project

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I recently tried to add a socket server to my project. Midway, I realised, I didn't have exactly the requirement so I ditched the idea instead opted for server events.

But, I still continue to have socket-related files in my node modules and Project.

I'm constantly getting this error

```
http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1654537406128
```

I deleted the package. lock-json but still I'm getting the following files in my node modules.

```
 "node_modules/faye-websocket"
"websocket-extensions",
"websocket-driver":
```

and many similar files.

Could you please let me know which among the following dependencies is creating these socket related modules in my project.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "svg-url-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-jest": "^25.5.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.0",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "preact": "^10.2.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "rootDir": "./",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  }
}
```